# Figuring out $\int_1^k \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}} = \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}}$

Tags: calculus

This was a question from a previous calculus exam.

"If $\int_1^k \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}} = \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}}$ (where k is a constant > 1), find the value of k."

So far I've tried to rewrite it as $\int_1^k \frac{x^4 \ dx}{x^5 \sqrt{x^5-1}}$
Is it viable to use substitution by parts and use something like $x^5-1 =u$?

Comment: You're going in the right way.

Comment: Maybe they want $\int_1^k=\int_k^\infty$.  Your substitution is fine, maybe $x^5-1=u^2$ is better.

Comment: And by the way, there is no such thing as "Substitution by parts". It's simply called "Integration using Substitution".

Answer (score 2):

Using André Nicolas's good suggestion, use $x^5-1=u^2$ that is to say $x=\sqrt[5]{u^2+1}$, $dx=\frac{2 u}{5 \left(u^2+1\right)^{4/5}}$ from which $$I=\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^5-1}}=\frac 25\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\frac 25 \tan ^{-1}(u)=\frac 25 \tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{x^5-1})$$ Going to the definite integrals, we then have $$\int_1^k \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}}= \frac{2}{5} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{k^5-1}\right)$$ $$ \int_k^\infty \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^5-1}}=\frac{\pi }{5}-\frac{2}{5} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{k^5-1}\right)$$ So, you have to solve for $k$ $$\frac{2}{5} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{k^5-1}\right)=\frac{\pi }{5}-\frac{2}{5} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{k^5-1}\right)$$ that is to say $$ \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{k^5-1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ Take the tangent of each side and this leads to $k^5-1=1$ that is to say $k=2^{1/5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^5-1}}$$
is a positive continuous function on $(1+\infty)$, hence for any $k\in (1,+\infty)$ we have that
$$ \int_{1}^{k}f(x)\,dx \color{red}{<}\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{5}.$$